# Test Batch with Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I create a batch and everything work well
I do some unittest and it's work well too
I'm trying to do integration test my batch following spring-batch documentation but i don't understand my errors.

Here my batch config

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value="/batch.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = false)
public class BatchConfiguration {

   @Autowired
   DataSource dataSource;
   @Autowired
   PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

   @Bean
   public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
       JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
       factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
       factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
       factory.afterPropertiesSet();
       return (JobRepository) factory.getObject();
   }

   @Bean
   public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
      SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
       launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
       return launcher;
   }

}
```

a example of one of my batch

```
@Component
@AutomaticLogging
public class TimeoutFormJob {    
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Value("${batch.timeoutForm.chunk}")
    int chunk;

    @Autowired
    TimeoutFormReader reader;


    @Autowired
    TimeoutFormProcessor processor;

    @Autowired
    public TimeoutFormWriter writer;

    @Bean
    public Step createStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("timeoutFormStep").<MyFormEntity, MyFormEntity>chunk(chunk).reader(reader).processor(processor).writer(writer).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job createJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("timeoutFormJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(createStep()).end().build();
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "${batch.timeoutForm.cron}")
    public void perform() throws Exception {
        JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(createJob(), param);
    }
}
```

The configuration of my testConfiguration

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestConfig {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
       }
}
```

and the test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class TimeoutFormJobTest {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncher;

    @Test
    public void testIntegration_batch() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(1, myService.findFormNotfinish().size());
        jobLauncher.launchJob();
        assertEquals(0, myService.findFormNotfinish().size());
    }
```

}

I got error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'a.b.c.batch.TimeoutFormJobTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jobLauncher'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I tried to add to the ConfigTest

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;
@Autowired
PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

@Autowired
SimpleJobLauncher jobLaucher;
@Autowired
JobRepository jobRepository;
@Autowired
@Qualifier("timeoutFormJob")
Job job;


@Bean
public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
    SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    return launcher;
}

@Bean
public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return (JobRepository) factory.getObject();
}

@Bean
public JobLauncherTestUtils getJobLauncherTestUtils(){
    JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();
    jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(job);
    jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobLauncher(jobLaucher);
    return jobLauncherTestUtils;
}
```

and i got the error

```
>***************************
>APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>***************************
>Description:
>
>Field job in a.b.c.Application >required a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' that could not be >found.
>
>Action:
>Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' in your >configuration
```

I tried to change the

`@Qualifier("timeoutFormJob)
 Job job`

by

`@Autowired
TimeoutFormJob jobConfig;
...
jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(jobconfig.createJob());`

But i got

> No qualifying bean of type 'a.b.c.batch.config.TimeoutFormJob' available

I don't understand error. I tried to follow exactly the spring documentation and nothing works...
I tried to find solution on stackoverflow but i don't find example with batch declaration annotation

> #### EDIT

I remove everything to start from zero

I looked the doc of SpringBatchTest and tried id but i got other few error
I must add @EnableAutoConfiguration (even if i already got it in ConfigTest)

And i saw in the spring doc the @ContextConfiguration to add the Job
I must add all reader/processor/writer/services/my mappers used in the batch...

now it look like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Sql({"classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-h2.sql", "classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql"})
@SpringBatchTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BatchConfiguration.class, TimeoutFormJob.class, Reader.class, Processor.class, Writer.class, ServiceA.class, MapperA.class, HelperMapper.class, ServiceB.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestBatch {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;
    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired
    private MyRepo myRepo;

    @Test
    public void myBatchTest() {
        assertEquals(0, myRepo.findAll().size());
        entityManager.persist(new MyEntity());
        assertEquals(1, myRepo.findAll().size());
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
        Assert.assertEquals("COMPLETED", jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
        assertEquals(0, myRepo.findAll().size());
    }

}
```

But when addind @ContextConfiguration I can't use embedded database anymore... when i try to persist i got an

> Error: no transaction in progress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a bean of type `JobLauncherTestUtils` in your test context. Something like:

```
@Bean
public JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils() {
    return new JobLauncherTestUtils();
}
```

For the record, Spring Batch v4.1 [introduced](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/whatsnew.html#whatsNewTesting) a new annotation called `@SpringBatchTest` that automatically adds the `JobLauncherTestUtils` to your context. For more details, please refer to the [Creating a Unit Test Class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/testing.html#creatingUnitTestClass) section of the reference documentation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I try it but i got another probleme... i edited my post

Comment: The new error means the transaction manager is not correctly configured in Spring Batch. You need to add a bean of type `BatchConfigurer` to your context and override `getTransactionManager` to return your transaction manager (See example here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig). Note this works only for v4.1+.

Comment: I tried to remove my persist to not have the no transaction in progress and just launch the batch but i got error "Existing transaction detected in JobRepository, please fix this (e.g remove transactional annontation) in my BatchConfiguration i create a job repository with an autowired datasource, the datasource is well the h2 database created by the JpaDataTest annontation

Comment: When i create the BatchConfigurer Bean and override getTransactionManager i got an StackOverFlow error

Comment: Sorry I can't follow anymore. There are a lot of details and code in your question. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I will try to help.